# Jquery function not working for two or more forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello all i have below jquery function to enable submit only if the input has 1 or more values but i have the same many input and submit button on my page the jquery function is wrking fine for 1st form but it doesnt work for other forms.

Script:

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#textbox").bind("change keyup", function () 
    {      
        if ($("#textbox").val() != "")
            $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        else
            $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="textbox" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

<form action="http://localhost/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="textbox" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

<form action="http://localhost/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="textbox" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

When I type anything in 1st textbox the submit button getting activated and working fine but if i add any values in second or third text box the submit button is not getting activated.

Comment: IDs in computing are generally used to **uniquely** identify something. You are using the same ID multiple times, errors ensue.

Comment: Have you tried to use a class instead of an id as a selector? You should know that you must not assign the same id to multiple elements within the same page. Edit: @lee: damn, you beat me up ;-)

Comment: thank you so much. it works for me. you guys are rocks. thank you so much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can add only one element with id="textbox" on the same page.

Add some class name to inputs (e.g. "textbox"), and change selector '#textbox' to '.textbox' on event binding:

```
$(function () 
{
    $(".textbox").bind("change keyup", function () 
    {      
        if ($(this).val() != "")
            $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        else
            $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `class` instead of `id` as you cannot have more than one element with same `id`.

Also, you need to use `$(this)` inside the event handler to access the changed element.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".textbox").bind("change keyup", function () {      
                if ($(this).val() != "")
                    $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                else
                    $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
            });
        });
</script>

<form action="http://localhost/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="textbox" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

<form action="http://localhost/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="textbox" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

<form action="http://localhost/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="textbox" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you are using the same `ID's` for more `div` in `html` and this is NO good. Id's are unique.
Use a `class` instead. Otherwise it won't work with `classes` neither , you should try using 3 different divs or `$.each()` function or recogninizing on `keyup()`